# Access Angular's data binding inside a dynamically added DOM element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a table row that I can dynamically add into an existing table using some jQuery like so:

```
$("#add-item").click(function(){
    var itemRow = "<tr><td><span contenteditable='true'><a href='#'>Edit me<a/></span></td></tr>";
    $("#job-table").hide(0).append(itemRow).fadeIn(500);
});
```

I also have some data-binding that I can do with Angular like so:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
    <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>
</div>
```

What I want is to have something like this:

```
$("#add-item").click(function(){
    var itemRow = "<tr><td><span contenteditable='true'><a href='http://something.com/{{content.url}}'>content.url<a/></span></td></tr>";
    $("#job-table").hide(0).append(itemRow).fadeIn(500);
});
```

The problem is that angular can't access this dynamically loaded element because it's not available at load time.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: On a side note, you should be using directives for DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to forget everything you know about jQuery. Put an "items" array in your scope and use an `ng-repeat`.

psuedocode:

```
<tr ng-repeat = "item in items">
<td><span contenteditable='true'><a ng-href='http://something.com/{{item.url}}'>item.url<a/></span></td>
</tr>
```

Now use `ng-click` to trigger adding an item to the items array and you're good to go. No jQuery required. It can even be as simple as `<button ng-click="items.push({url:'what'})">add</button>` and it will automatically appear.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VEbsU/1/ showing a full example

Comment: Great example and explanation.